# How to properly import Android projects in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been fighting with Android Studio for 2 dayys because I cannot import 2 eclipse projects in the IDE.Here what I have done.

The projects are 2 Eclipse projects and I export them by doing FILE > EXPORT > Generate build.gradle files.

When I try to import the projects in Android Studio, I have this error :

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'SourceFiles'
You are using Gradle version 1.11, which is not supported. Please use version 1.9.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project Gradle settings
```

As you see I use the latest distribution of gradle (version 1.11) and it still does not work. 
Can someone show me the proper way to import those projects in Android Studio?

I am on 
Linux OpenSuse version 13.1
Android Studio : 0.4.2
Java : 1.7

[EDIT] My project is comprised of directory `Sourcefiles` which contains 2 sub-directories `Skeletons` and `Testcase`. `Skeletons` contains the source files and `TestCase` contains the test case associated with the project in `Skeletons`.

Here are the build.gradle generated by Eclipse : 
In `SourceFiles` level :

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.9'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
```

In the Skeletons level :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

In the testcase level directory :

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Skeletons:FragmentsLab')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I also have to admit that I am still a noob in gradle. 
   I also updated the Android Studio the latest version in the canary channel and references   the verison 1.9 of gradle in my project. 
Any help would be appreciated.

I would want to use the Eclipse IDE but it keeps crashing.

Comment: Have you tried installing version 1.9?

Comment: As per http://tools.android.com/recent *"the new importer in Studio is the preferred way to migrate projects to Gradle"* - try if importing eclipse projects directly works better than exporting from eclipse.

Comment: why should I install version 1.9 when I have version 1.11?

Comment: @dimitri Because 1.11 is not supported by Android Studio 0.4.2.
It requires gradle 1.9.
You can use gradle 1.10 with 0.4.3+

Comment: Can you publish the build.gradle files which were generated?

Comment: After an hour spent in searching workarounds, i found a way to get android studio 0.5.0 work with gradle 1.11, with gradle plugin 0.9.+. I followed the instruction here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating_to_09, and changed some others things in build.gradle, according to gradle docs.

Answer (score 0):

Latest gradle versions have many issues, you should really try to use an older one, 1.9 is fine. Add this to the root build.gradle and run `gradle wrapper` from console:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.9'
}
```

It should create a gradle path in your project. After that, use `gradlew` instead of `gradle` in command line or pick a "customizable gradle wrapper" option when creating a project in Android Studio.

If you'll encounter further issues with versions change the value of `distributionUrl` in `gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`